# SQL Server: Create a specific ID counter

Tags: sql, sql-server, increment

I have the following view in MS SQL Server:

```
TestR   SW  ID
--------------
Test1   A   P1
Test1   A   P2
Test2   B   P1
Test2   B   P2
Test5   A   P1
Test5   A   P2
Test5   B   P1
Test5   B   P2
Test3   A   P3
Test3   A   P4
Test3   B   P3
Test3   B   P4
Test4   A   P5
Test6   A   P1
```

As you can see for the Test1,2,5 I have different SW but the same ID (P1;P2). In Test3 I have different SW integrated and the ID (P3;P4)twice. Test4 has only one SW and ID. Test6 is similar to Test1,2,5 but it has only the ID P1.

What I want to accomplish is to integrate a specific increment IDCount:
As an example I want not to increment IDCount when **Testn.ID =Testn.ID**, because they have the same IDs. In Test3 I increment one, because the ID do not fit to Test1,Test2...In Test4 I also have to increment. In Test6 the ID P1 occured in Test1,Test2 but the dataset is not the same. The column SW has no impact on the IDCount.

```
IDCount    TestR   SW  ID
-------------------------         
1          Test1   A   P1
1          Test1   A   P2
1          Test2   B   P1
1          Test2   B   P2
1          Test5   A   P1
1          Test5   A   P2
1          Test5   B   P1
1          Test5   B   P2
2          Test3   A   P3
2          Test3   A   P4
2          Test3   B   P3
2          Test3   B   P4
3          Test4   A   P5
4          Test6   A   P1
```

I hope you can understand my issue and I would be grateful for some help.Currently I used the commando: Rank() OVER (ORDER BY TestR) AS IDCount but this works only for Test3. I think the main problem is to check whether the different TestR had the same IDs.

Comment: What if test5 rows are adedd with ID set (P1,P2)?

Comment: It will get the same ID as Test1,2. I have forget this case...thanks for the question

Comment: Why `Test6   A P1`  is 4 Instead of 1?

Comment: @Neer: Yes Test6 A P1 is 4, because Test6 has only P1 and not the full ID set of Test1,2,5(P1;P2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering by setcode which is concatenation of ordered distinct IDs

```
with tbl(TestR,SW,ID) as(
    select * 
    from (
        values
         ('Test1','A','P1')
        ,('Test1','A','P2')
        ,('Test2','B','P1')
        ,('Test2','B','P2')
        ,('Test5','A','P1')
        ,('Test5','A','P2')
        ,('Test5','B','P1')
        ,('Test5','B','P2')
        ,('Test3','A','P3')
        ,('Test3','A','P4')
        ,('Test3','B','P3')
        ,('Test3','B','P4')
        ,('Test4','A','P5')
        ,('Test6','A','P1')
    ) t(TestR,SW,ID)
)
, sets  as (
    select  t1.*, 
         ( select distinct '-'+t2.ID 
           from tbl t2 
           where t2.TestR = t1.TestR
           order by '-'+t2.ID 
           for xml path('')
          ) setcode
    from tbl t1 
)
select dense_rank() over(order by setcode) as IDCount, TestR, SW, ID, setcode
from sets
order by dense_rank() over(order by setcode),TestR;
```

**EDIT**
A bit different order, by min(TestR) in the group

```
with ...
)
, sets  as (
    select  t1.*, 
         ( select distinct '-'+t2.ID 
           from tbl t2 
           where t2.TestR = t1.TestR
           order by '-'+t2.ID 
           for xml path('')
          ) setcode
    from tbl t1 
), keys as (
    select *, min(TestR) over(partition by setcode) key1
    from sets
)
select dense_rank() over(order by key1) as IDCount, TestR, SW, ID, setcode
from keys
order by dense_rank() over(order by key1),TestR;
```

Comment: I have a question to your query, especially to the WITH clause. Instead of the values I want to get the data from a table. So it should be something like this:                                                                                                       with tbl(TestR,SW,ID) as(
    select * from [tableX]...    When I execute this I get an error and all fields are shown red underlined
    from (

Comment: You needn't  first with at all, it just itroduces sample data. It should be `with sets as ( select... from  [tableX] t1) ...`. You may need to rename columns in my query according to real columns in [tableX].